# save checkbox value and get the value to se if checked or unchecked

Tags: php

How do i create a simple checkbox i, i wanted to add a simple checkbox so when its checked it should save the checked status so when it refreshes page it should remain how it is, and then add a if statement to that checkbox.

i am a a beginner and fast learner i simple example will help me build new ideas from your code,will appreciate if you can share thanks.

am not sure if this is right

add this code someone in user profile php

demo.php

```
 <form action="checkbox-form.php" method="post">
Do you need wheelchair access?
<input type="checkbox" name="formWheelchair" value="Yes" />
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

checkbox-form.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['formWheelchair']) && 
   $_POST['formWheelchair'] == 'Yes') 
{
    echo "Need wheelchair access.";
}
else
{
    echo "Do not Need wheelchair access.";
}    

?>
```

now how do i save the checked value and when refeshed it should remain, and when unchecked then save that value again.

Comment: For how long do you need this option to be saved? Until you close the browser or forever?

Comment: for ever. when its checked then save it for good, when its unchecked then save it for good , its all onto the user . this is something am trying to add as an option  like enable or disable feature permenantly.  so next time user loggs into site this checkbox wil remain how he left it.

Comment: Then you could use a database. not just php

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `checked` to the checkbox `input`. So that,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="formWheelchair" value="Yes" />
```

becomes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="formWheelchair" value="Yes" checked />
```

when the user has this option enabled.

This is the HTML part. Now, you'd need to have some kind of persistence layer (a database) where you retrieve the user's settings.

I don't see any db-related code in your OP, so you probably need to add this.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form try to check if the post is set or check if the value is what you set (in this case the string "Yes").

So..
isset($_POST['formWheelchair'])

Which means the checkbox exist/has a value/is checked

Check for the specific value ('Yes'):
($_POST['formWheelchair'] == 'Yes')